# I can't get the SKU value for a commerce product in a rule action

Tags: entities, rules, commerce

I created a rule to be fired when a "New Commerce product is saved" Then I set a action to create a **Product Display** node and and another action to  set the title for the **Product Display** to be the same as for the **new commerce product**. So far so good.

Now I need to create another action to set the field **product** of the **Product display** to be the same as the **Commerce product SKU**.

Here is the problem since I can not get this value. I tried to add a condition of the type "Entity has field" but it seems like the SKU vale is not a field at all.

How can I accomplish with this?

Code for the rule:

```
{ "rules_create_product_display" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create Product Display",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "commerce" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_product_insert" ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "product_display",
            "param_title" : "[commerce-product:title]",
            "param_author" : [ "commerce-product:creator" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "product_display_created" : "Created Product Display" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "product-display-created" ], "immediate" : 1 } },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : [ "product-display-created:edit-url" ] } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Product display created. You can edit it at: [product-display-created:nid]" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the SKU for the product you must first use two conditions in your rule to assure that you are dealing with the right type, these are :

- Entity is of type `commerce-line-item`
- Entity has field `commerce_product`

Just as an example this Rule export applies a discount ( 5_eur_disc ) to a product with an SKU of *SKU-FOO-ITEM* after checking that the discount dates are current.

```
{ "commerce_discount_rule_discount_discount_per_sku" : {
    "LABEL" : "Discount per SKU",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "commerce_discount_date",
      "rules",
      "commerce_discount",
      "commerce_product_reference"
    ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "commerce_discount_date_condition" : { "commerce_discount" : "5_eur_discount" } },
      { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ], "type" : "commerce_line_item" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ], "field" : "commerce_product" } },
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product:sku" ],
          "value" : "SKU-FOO-ITEM"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_discount_fixed_amount" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "commerce_discount" : "5_eur_discount"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```